# iHealth Gluco monitoring system(BLE device),not able to discover the device

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios9.2

I'm currently trying to connect the iHealth gluco device with our own application via bluetooth. 
I have used Service UUID as:1808, characteristicID:2A18
 here i'm not able to connect with that Peripheral device.

```
In viewDidLoad:
centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];



// method called whenever the device state changes.
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    // Determine the state of the peripheral
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");

      [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
    }
}




    - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
    {

NSLog("advertisement data :%@",advertisementData);
        NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
        if (![localName isEqual:@""]) {

            [self.centralManager stopScan];
            self.polarH7HRMPeripheral = peripheral;
            peripheral.delegate = self;
            [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
        }
    }
```

here the above method is not triggering at all....Please help me in connecting the device and to read the data from the device.

Comment: You need to check that your `CBCentralManager` is ready to scan. Is that the case? Also, you need to keep reference of `centralManager`, else it will be released too soon. If it doesn't work yet, put `services` at `nil` for the scan. Then log the advertisement data in `didDiscoverPeripheral:`. Plus is that method even called?

Comment: i have replaced services with 'nil', and even didDiscoverPeripheral method is also not triggering..

Comment: You only did 2 of the mandatory things: Keep a reference of `centralManager` (strong property). Also, implement the didUpdateState delegate method and start the scan only if it's ready.

Comment: declared strong property....even i'm not able to detect the peripheral

Comment: You need to scan only in the case `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`. So don't start the scan before, it's useless. You should have a log in console. Also, log all the `advertisementData`.

Comment: this is the advertisement data log: {
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = 0808A072D1BCEC;
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        7889
    );
}

Comment: Your device does say (publicly, it may have it if you discover them once connected) that it has not the service  "1808", but it has the "7889" one. That's why you couldn't even find it before if you scan for 1808;

Comment: thank you.....but now how to read the data from the device? and how to get the characteristic ID?Please let me know

Comment: Well. Now, scan the services. It will trigger the didDiscoverService delegate method. Then scan characteristics. It will trigger the didDiscoverCharacteristic delegate method, then read them. You should look at a tutorial or at the Apple Doc/Sample example to understand the whole logic.

Comment: - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }
    
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        
        NSLog(@"service uuid :%@",service.UUID);
        NSLog(@"Discovered service %@",service.description);
      
        
        
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A35"]] forService:service];//TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID
    }
    // Discover other characteristics
}